# How to emulate Ctrl+I pressed on a terminal process

Tags: java, terminal

I have a process that I started a (non-Java) CLI process with Java and I want to programatically send Ctrl+I key combination to it.

Is it possible?

Comment: yes. it is possible. java key bindings should do the trick.

Comment: @andrewdleach Maybe I am missing something, but I don't see how this will help me to programmaticaly send a Ctrl+I to a remote CLI process.

Comment: Sorry, what does ctrl+I do in the console? Does it map to an interrupt?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I don't think so. It's just a control symbol.

Comment: No.  It cannot be done with Java, unless you're willing to make use of JNI.

Comment: @VGR Could you please provide more details?

Comment: If the external process is looking for a Ctrl-I character (which is the same as Tab, by the way) on its standard input, GreenGiant's solution would work.  Since that didn't work, the process is apparently looking for key presses on its console (tty), something to which other programs simply do not have access.  You would need to write native code to create a virtual tty and have the process use that;  JNI is how you allow Java to invoke native code as part of the Java program.

Comment: @VGR Thank you for a good comment, this seems like a good approach. Feel free to convert it into an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: @OP: Are you using some OS (such as MS Windows, GNU/Linux, MacOS X, etc)? Would you mind naming it?

Comment: I am using Linux. I don't care about other OSs in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the external process is looking for a Ctrl-I character (which is the same as Tab, by the way) on its standard input, GreenGiant's solution would work.  Since that didn't work, the process is apparently looking for key presses on its console (tty), something to which other programs simply do not have access.  You would need to write native code to create a virtual tty and have the process use that.  JNI is how you allow Java to invoke native code as part of the Java program.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to send KeyListener Events in a console window without the use of GUI.

See the following for more details:

[Key Bindings in Command Prompt with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487175/key-bindings-in-command-prompt-with-java)

and

[Java key listener in Commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005574/java-key-listener-in-commandline)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I was asking about. I need to programatically send Ctrl+I to a different CLI process from Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you started the other program using [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), then you might be able to send the control sequence by writing the appropriate bytes to the process's input stream.

I'm not sure what the actual byte sequence is that you need to send, but [based on what I'm finding](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/841471-how-send-ctrl-s-ctrl-x-over-serial-port), it seems like Ctrl+A is 1, Ctrl+B is 2, etc.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "..." );
Process process = pb.start();
OutputStream stream = process.getOutputStream();
stream.write( 'I' - 'A' + 1 ); // send Ctrl+I
stream.flush();
```